# How to help my child make online video friends?

Tags: friends, computer

My son is seven and bilingual.
Japan has a lot of COVID paranoia so children can't meet after school. Currently he does get play in person at his after school English program but we can't afford to keep paying for that. How can I make online video friends like you see as the online schooling sort of contact? He has friends at his normal school but I wouldn't call those friends a good influence.  It would great if he could have online friends to encourage play outside of school time. How can I arrange those online friends?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're on Facebook, or even if it's used much in Japan, but it actually has a decent platform to allow kids to connect.  If you create a Messenger Kids account for him, you will be able to link him up with any other kids that have an account linked to any of your Facebook friends (i.e. their children).

As arved mentioned in [their response](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/43254/17176), you probably don't want your child just connecting with random children on the internet; you probably want some sort of connection to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice ask in your friends circle if they know a person with kids in his age.

1. You can trust your friends that their kids are not a bad influence
2. At that age kids usually need help keeping their relation going if they don't see each other regularly.